# Model person with several first names and one primary first name in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an API using Django Rest Framework. The database engine is PostgreSQL.

When I navigate to the Persons API I can enter Identity number, last name and choose first names from a predefined list, as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

This is not the functionality that I intended to create

How can I change my code so that I can enter any number of first names for a person and then am able to mark/choose one of those fist names as primary first name?

This is my models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='persons')

    identity_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    primary_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class FirstName(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    person= models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='first_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('person',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.first_name)
```

This is my serializers.py

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    first_names = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('created', 'updated', 'url', 'owner',
                  'identity_number', 'last_name', 'first_names')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Django to know that the primary first name should be a "pointer" to a first name instance, you should modify your model a bit:

```
class Person(models.Model):
        primary_first_name = models.ForeignKey('FirstName')
```

The second part of your question is a bit tricky. So you want the Django Rest Framework to generate an "admin interface" to create some first names and then allow you to tick the certain as the primary? I guess you'd better stick with the `django.contrib.admin`, which has inlines. DRF certainly doesn't have such a complex interface, after all, it's just for the objects (de)serialization.

Comment: Regarding the second part of my question: how about if I don't need a drop down in the rest API interface - I can let the front end handle that - but I want to store multiple first names per Person and be able to mark one of them as primary, what is a good way to set this up in the Model?

Comment: Your models look quite good for that task: you have a model to store first names, and you have a primary_first_name indicator. If you're asking how to create these models via REST - you should first create a `Person` (1st API call) and get it's `pk`, then create a bunch of `FirstNames` linked to that `pk` (and get theirs `pks`) and at last fill the `primary_first_name` with the needed `pk`. You could handle it via one REST call, but it definitely wil require more complex view handler.

Comment: I'm just wondering, did the answer solve your problem? If not, please share your solution with us to make this post complete. If yes, consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.